# MongoDB specify size Exception

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have an Exception for my code :
To test the tailable cursor manually insert documents into the test.capped collection while this program is running and verify that they are echoed to the console window.

```
public static class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        try
        {
            var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://distnatserver/?safe=true");
            var database = server["test"];



            if (database.CollectionExists("capped"))
            {
                database.DropCollection("capped");
            }
            var collectionOptions = CollectionOptions.SetCapped(true).SetMaxDocuments(5);
            var commandResult = database.CreateCollection("capped", collectionOptions);
            var collection = database["capped"];



            BsonValue lastId = BsonMinKey.Value;
            while (true)
            {
                var query = Query.GT("_id", lastId);
                var cursor = collection.Find(query)
                    .SetFlags(QueryFlags.TailableCursor | QueryFlags.AwaitData)
                    .SetSortOrder("$natural");
                using (var enumerator = (MongoCursorEnumerator<BsonDocument>)cursor.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                        {
                            var document = enumerator.Current;
                            lastId = document["_id"];
                            ProcessDocument(document);
                        }
                        else {
                            if (enumerator.IsDead)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            if (!enumerator.IsServerAwaitCapable)
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void ProcessDocument(
        BsonDocument document
    )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
    }
}
```

> Unhandled exception:
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command 'create' failed: specify size: when capped is true (response: { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "specify size: when capped is true", "code" : 14832 })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), when creating a capped collection you must specify the maximum size of the collection in bytes, for example:

```
db.createCollection( "log", { capped: true, size: 100000 } )
```

Comment: thnx it solve the problem for capped true, and give me another exception :
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Driver.Operations.Cursor iEnumerator to type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor Enumerator for heer using (var enumerator = (MongoCursorEnumerator<BsonDocument>)cursor.GetEnumerator())

Comment: Do you need the cast? Can you use `var enumerator = cursor.GetEnumerator();` instead ?

Comment: it will show error for enumerator.IsDead and enumerator.IsServerAwaitCapable (enumerator does not contain a definition for IsDead  and IsServerAwaitCapable )

Comment: Does it work if you use this: `var enumerator = new MongoCursorEnumerator<T>(cursor).GetEnumerator()`

Comment: not working, but when I chnage T with BsonDocument give me ('MongoCursorEnumerator<BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'GetEnumerator' and no extension method 'GetEnumerator' accepting a first argument of type 'MongoCursorEnumer)